# EF4 entity set: how to get the current count from TPH objects?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have this very simple TPH Model.
When I add an object using `context.TIImport.AddObject(tiObj)`
and then call `context.TIImport.Count()` - the value doesn't include the new object?

I want to be able to add multiple objects before hitting context.SaveChanges()

[image]

```
var context = new CodeFirstContainer();

var g = new TIGuarantee
            {
                Id = 1,
                AccountNumber = "123",
                Amount = 123
            };
            context.TIImports.AddObject(g);

            var il = new TIImportLoan
            {
                Id = 2,
                AccountNumber = "123",
                Amount = 123
            };
            context.TIImports.AddObject(il);

            var i = context.TIImports.Count(); // = 0

            context.SaveChanges();
            var j = context.TIImports.Count(); // = 2
        }
```

Is there any way to tell how many objects are in the collection WITHOUT calling SaveChanges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by going into the ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager and check all entities with EntityState as Added to the right Collection and include that with your count. Why you want to do this however is not clear. When you perform a read, these entities wont be included untill you actually persist them to the underlying datastore with SaveChanges(); If your aim is not to make the changes final, maybe you should look into transactions then?

Comment: Thanks: It is to do with setting keys in SQL-CE as it won't allow me to use Identity columns.  However, I was hoping to save in batches, rather than after each item is added - but get the next Id/Key as I do so.